# How do I merge 2 dataframes based on whether values fall into a particular bucket?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have:

```
edu_data = [['school', 5, 18], ['college', 19, 23], ['grad-school', 24, 28]] 
edu = pd.DataFrame(edu_data, columns = ['Education', 'Low-Age', 'High-Age']) 
print(edu)
     Education  Low-Age  High-Age
0       school        5        18
1      college       19        23
2  grad-school       24        28
```

And then I have another table with people's ages:

```
data = [['tom', 5], ['nick', 28], ['juli', 14], ['jack', 30]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age']) 
print(df)
   Name  Age
0   tom    5
1  nick   28
2  juli   14
3  jack   30
```

How would I get a table where I would match df['Age'] against the range between  edu["Low-Age"] and edu["High-Age"]. If df['Age'] lies within the range then I would like to append edu["Education"] to df.

So I would expect my output to be:

```
   Name  Age Education
0   tom    5    school
1  nick   28    grad-school
2  juli   14    school
3  jack   30    NaN
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pd.cut`:

```
bins = sorted([edu['Low-Age'][0]] + edu['High-Age'].to_list())

df['Education'] = pd.cut(df.Age, bins=bins,
        include_lowest=True,
        labels=edu.Education)
```

Output:

```
   Name  Age    Education
0   tom    5       school
1  nick   28  grad-school
2  juli   14       school
3  jack   30          NaN
```

Comment: `pd.cut` is a nice solution :) +1

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html

Answer (score 2):

Use `IntervalIndex` and `map`

```
edu = edu.set_index(pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(edu['Low-Age'], edu['High-Age'], closed='both'))

df['Education'] = df.Age.map(edu.Education)

In [488]: df
Out[488]:
   Name  Age    Education
0   tom    5       school
1  nick   28  grad-school
2  juli   14       school
3  jack   30          NaN
```